# All connected subgraphs from adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

Given is an undirected graph with $n$ nodes and their $n \times n$ adjacency matrix $A$. How to find all connected subgraphs with $m$ nodes either by brute force or by an effective algorithm?

In case the solution depends strongly on the parameters, the special case of interest is for $n=10000, m=4$.

$\\$

### Example for $\bf{n=6, m=4}$

For the graph below with 6 nodes the adjacency matrix is

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

In total  5 subgraphs of 4 nodes can be found:
$[1,2,3,4]; [2,3,4,5]; [3,4,5,6]; [2,3,4,6]; [1,2,3,6]$.

[image]

**Edit**

A very fast solution for this problem was given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751315/12842085).

Comment: With $k=1$ it seems as if you are asking for all the connected subgraphs with $m=4$ vertices. If so, restate the problem that way. I suspect it's much easier than the general case.

Comment: Actually, I think based on the example that the question is about all connected induced subgraphs, since each subset of the vertices is listed only once. Also, how efficient do you want your algorithm to be? Brute force can give you $n^m/m!$ pretty easily when $k=1$, and you can't generally do better unless you know something about the graph (since your list needs to be that long for the complete graph)

Comment: If you can do the $k=1$ case, you can do any case. For instance, when $k=3$, you can just subtract 2 from every cell in the matrix (capping it at 0) and find all $k=1$ subgraphs of that new graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can convert an adjacency matrix to adjacency list in $O(n^{2})$ time.
We can consider the adjacency list data-structure..

If you want a brute force solution:
Just go over all possible $n\choose m$ cases and check if the sub-graph on those $m$ vertices is connected or not (using BFS/DFS). This would take ${n \choose m} \cdot O(m)$ time.

If you want an efficient solution:  Pick a vertex and do the following:

-(assume it is included), After deleting the vertex, recursively solve the problem on its neighbors with $m \gets m-1$ and so on till $m = 0$.

-(assume it is not included), simply delete this vertex.

The complexity actually depends on the type of graph (especially, the degrees of the vertices). For a complete graph, $n \choose m$ is the lower bound, whatever the algorithm may be. Even for a tree, $\Omega(n^{m-1})$ is the lower bound whatever the algorithm may be (consider a star graph).

Comment: @granularbastard Hi. Currently, I am occupied with some other work. Will answer you in a week!